# Положение курсора при развертывании сниппета в Sublime text

Tags: cursor, sublime-text-3

Решил заморочится созданием сниппетов в sublime text для удобства работы, но наткнулся на неприятность при развертывании сниппета курсор улетает в конец всей иерархии а хотелось бы чтобы он вставал там где мне нужно, читал в нете что у него есть подобная настройка, но по моим запросам гугл ничего не выводит((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В теле сниппета укажите `${1}` - при вставке, курсор будет на этом месте

```
<snippet>
  <content><![CDATA[
Rails.logger.info '#########################################'
Rails.logger.info ${1}
Rails.logger.info '#########################################'
]]></content>
  <tabTrigger>logger</tabTrigger>
  <scope>source.ruby</scope>
</snippet>
```

После ввода имени сниппета `logger` и `<Tab>` курсор встанет в следующую позицию

```
Rails.logger.info '#########################################'
Rails.logger.info |
Rails.logger.info '#########################################'
```

Comment: Да я смотрю можно обойтись и одной конструкцией ${1} Благодарю

Comment: Можно просто `${1}` перед тем местом, где должен стоять курсор.

Comment: Спасибо, за замечания, поправил ответ.